# Get weight combining edges in Networkx

Tags: python, list, graph, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

Hello I am using Networkx with Python to make some graphs.

After extracting the edges from a .CSV structured as "source" and "target"  I got a list of edges like this:

> ```
> edges = [(a,b), (a,c), (b,c), (a,b), (a,b), (a,c)]
> ```

Is there any way to build ( after creating a MultiDiGraph with these edges) a Directed Graph combining the equal edges getting the weights as the number of occurrences of the same edge, resulting in something like this:

> ```
> edges = [(a, b, weight = 3), (b, c, weight = 1), (a, c, weight = 2)]
> ```

I have achieved something similar transforming the csv to list and then to counter using the following code:

> ```
> reader = csv.reader(open('edges_list.csv', 'r')) 
> next(reader, None) 
> list_edges = list(reader)  
> count = Counter(map(tuple, list_edges))  
> list= [list(i) for i in count.items()] 
> list= [[k,v,w] for (k,v),w in list]
> ```

But I would like to know if there is some direct function in Networkx to combine parallel edges in a Multidirected Graph as weight to a Directed Graph.

Comment: Read the docs.  Or, since you have solved the problem, move on to something else.

Comment: @ravenspoint Reading the docs can be a great way to find a built in solution, if that solution exists. However, in the case where no such function exists (which seems to be the case in this point), it is difficult to read the docs so thoroughly that you can state with certainty that no such function exists, and asking for help with that on this site is absolutely warranted. So, in addition to being rudely terse, your comment is useless.

Comment: @Moses For a large file, you might find that it's faster to import the csv [as a numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt) and use the [unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function (with return_counts = True) than it is to use your Counter method after reading the file in with the csv module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a cursory search [through the docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html#methods) and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683114/2476977) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15598279/2476977) on this site, it seems like networkx does not have this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been reading the docs aswell but didn´t find anything. I will stick to use the method mentioned in your answer above.